# Disabling a widget using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have four buttons:

```
<button ng-disabled = "isDisabled1" ng-click="someFunc('isDisabled1')"></button>
<button ng-disabled = "isDisabled2" ng-click="someFunc('isDisabled2')"></button>
<button ng-disabled = "isDisabled3" ng-click="someFunc('isDisabled3')"></button>
<button ng-disabled = "isDisabled4" ng-click="someFunc('isDisabled4')"></button>
```

Now when `click event fires` on any one of the button it `calls the someFunc()` `function` and inside that function I want to `disable the button that was clicked.`

I am doing this inside the `controller`:

```
$scope.someFunc(toDisable){
    $scope.toDisable = true;
}
```

But that does not work. Any idea how. I am new to AngularJS.

Comment: `$scope[toDisable] = true`

Comment: @angabriel Yeah it works. Thanks a lot. Can you tell me why accessing toDisable as a property does not work. But accessing the same as an array member works?

Comment: because `$scope.isDisabled1`...`$scope.isDisabled4` do not exist yet. you can't access a property dynamically with the dot notation.

Comment: @angabriel Cant understand it.

Comment: `toDisable` is your parameter of the function. But `$scope.toDisable = true` does write a new variable named `toDisable` and not a variable named `toDisabled1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an map to store value

Ex : `$scope.isDisabled={
isDisabled1:false,
isDisabled2:false,
.
.
.
}`

and in

```
$scope.someFunc(toDisable){
$scope.isDisabled[toDisable]= true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

An alternative and simple way to do this is to use the `ng-click` directive to evaluate an expression that will manipulate the variable used in the `ng-disabled` directive.

e.g.

```
<button ng-disabled="ds1" ng-click="ds1 = true">btn1</button>
<button ng-disabled="ds2" ng-click="ds2 = true">btn2</button>
<button ng-disabled="ds3" ng-click="ds3 = true">btn3</button>
<button ng-disabled="ds4" ng-click="ds4 = true">btn4</button>
```

Associated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EDUmNwUnC6J7qVSLEiOr?p=preview).